# iPad Messages and FaceTime

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages, apple-id, facetime

I recently got a new phone and made a new Apple ID (which had my new phone number connected to it). I then logged into this new account onto my iPad, but then when I went to ‘send and receive’ in messages, it only showed my e-mail as an option; same with FaceTime. How do I add my new number?

Comment: FaceTime [& most apple services] work from your Apple ID... setting up 2 IDs is just not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are signed into FaceTime with your AppleID by going to FaceTime in the settings. Also make sure your contacts are syncing from iCloud to your phone if you have contacts stored in iCloud.